# How can I end a Thread in for Windows

Tags: c, multithreading, process, timer, terminate

Im doing a game in C using Threads for windows, but in a point of the game i need to stop some threads in a specific moment, I dont know either the function and the parameters that i need to stop a thread neither what it returns.

This 2 Function are the same, a simple timer that run until the counter reach limit, i want to stop the second thread whenever i want, without using  the second parameter of  WaitForSingleObject(hThread, Miliseconds).

```
DWORD WINAPI timer(LPVOID segundo)
{

    int counter = 0;
    while(counter<segundo)
    {
        counter++;
        gotoxy(30,5);
        printf("%d", counter);
        Sleep(1000);
    }
    return NULL;
}

DWORD WINAPI prueba(LPVOID segundo)
{
    int counter = 0;
    while(counter<segundo)
    {
        counter++;
        gotoxy(30,10);
        printf("%d", counter);
        Sleep(1000);
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    int limit = 5, *ptr;
    *ptr = limit;
    HANDLE hThread1, hThread2;
    DWORD time, probo;
    hThread1 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, timer, *ptr, 0, &time);
    hThread2 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, prueba, *ptr, 0, &probo);
    WaitForSingleObject(hThread2, INFINITE);
    WaitForSingleObject(hThread1,INFINITE);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do this? Threading works with cooperation. You signal a thread to do something and then wait until it has done so. Here you would signal the thread that you want it to pause and then wait until it has paused. It doesn't sounds as though that's what you had in mind which may be a symptom of a design flaw.

Answer (score 0):

Create an event using `CreateEvent(NULL,FALSE,FALSE,NULL)` function, pass this event handle into thread, then in the thread procedure, use `WaitForSingleObject(hEvent,1000)` instead. Whenever you want to stop the thread, call `SetEvent(hEvent)`, then in the thread proc, do:

```
DWORD retval = WaitForSingleObject(hEvent,1000);
if( retval != WAIT_TIMEOUT )
    return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

In C, one usually use a global `BOOL`, `bTerminated`, which is initially set to FALSE. The thread repeatedly checks its value, e.g. in your thread function `while(counter<segundo && !bTerminated)` would be written. Any other part of the code, which wants to stop the thread, should set `bTerminated` to `TRUE`, and wait for the thread to stop is needed, by calling `WaitForSingleObject`. If you have more than one thread, you can use such a logical variable for each thread.

This solution is also the standard approach in Delphi, but in this case the bTerminated variable is a field of the TThread class, and is set to true bay calling the `Terminate` method. There are similar implementations in C++, too.